# Hive performance optimization - CTEs

Tags: sql, hive, common-table-expression

Requesting your insight about how hive CTEs can be tuned for performance.  I have a query that looks something like this.  EDIT: note the two statements below have different mapping conditions, so the two WHERE conditions cannot be simply combined with an OR condition as suggested in the following comments.

```
WITH complex_query AS (
... big nasty HQL statement ...
)
SELECT complex_mapping_case FROM complex_query
WHERE condition_1
UNION ALL 
SELECT different_mapping_case FROM complex_query
WHERE condition_2
UNION ALL 
.... many more times....
```

Does Hive intelligently perform the CTE query once and store the results in memory (or on disk), or does it execute the CTE multiple times for each of the WHERE conditions?

And do you think that it is better to perform this as a CTE, or materialize it as a stage table with the optimal indexing, bucketing, and ordering?  Thanks!

Comment: i think the best way is to persist it as a temp table. From what i've seen, the cte definition gets called every time the cte name is referred to.

Comment: If performance is your goal, Spark is going to go heaps a lot faster than HQL...Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the union all will run that query multiple times.

It should perform more efficiently if you use

```
select * from cte
where condition_1 OR condition_2
```

rather than

```
select * from cte
where condition_1
  union all
select * from cte
where condition_2
```

If you must select from the cte multiple times my understanding is it reads from the disk each time.

My theory (only based on my limited experience) is that the performance gains from a temp table depend on how much Ram you have and you server settings

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Why are you using `union all`?  Why not just use `or`:

```
WITH complex_query AS (
... big nasty HQL statement ...
)
SELECT *
FROM complex_query
WHERE condition_1 OR condition_2 . . .
```

Comment: Sorry for my overly-simplistic example ... it is more complex than this.  There is different mapping logic for each of these selects -- for example source attribution using regex within a clickstream -- the conditions being very different for each of the scenarios.